# Delete Huggingface Cache - NLLB etc

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

Every time I clear my cache, it keeps building up NLLB cache which I don't use, I have deleted everything related to NLLB and can't find the .cache folder for huggingface, but this cache keeps building up when I clear them.

How do I get rid of it permanently to stop it from building?

[image]

No more cache once deleted

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you please provide a few more details (e.g. How do you delete which cache?)?

Comment: Everything in that picture, they keep rebuilding for some reason

Comment: My question was, how do you delete which cache? Also, do you know when these files are recreated?